# Boolean not changing as expected

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

ANSWERED - Racing Condition

So this is the class for the game I'm making that generates obstacles, each time an obstacle goes off screen it removes the obstacle and adds to the score. This works fine, however the Boolean (plusScore) doesn't change to true when expected.

```
public void update() {
            //
            if(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).getRectangle().top >= Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
                int xStart = (int)(Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
                obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
                obstacles.remove(obstacles.size() - 1);
                score += 10;
                plusScore = true; //Problem here
                tempTime = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            if (tempTime + 5 <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                plusScore = false; //Unsure if working as relying on above
            }
        }
```

This (below) is where I'm calling for the Boolean, I included the first part of the method as I wasn't sure if there could be possible conflict.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
       ob.draw(canvas);
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTextSize(100);
   paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   canvas.drawText(" " + score, 50, 50 + paint.descent() - paint.ascent(), paint);

   if(plusScore) { //This is what the Boolean should effect
       Paint paint2 = new Paint();
       paint2.setTextSize(100);
       paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       drawPlusScore(canvas, paint2, "+10!");
   }
}
```

[Just to clarify the draw method works fine when there is no if statement.]
If the issue is obvious I apologise, I'm following a tutorial for the first time and decided to try something for myself.

Comment: is this condition met: obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).getRectangle().top >= Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT

Comment: Yes it works and increases the score by 10 each time they go off the screen (I've checked in the emulator)

Comment: I suspect a racing condition. Try to reset the boolean in `draw` not in `update` -> put `plusScore = false;` as the first statement in `if(plusScore)`. Are `update` and `draw` called on different threads? If so, try making it volatile.

Comment: @Fildor That's done the trick thank you so much I really appreciate it, could I ask how you suspected a racing condition?

Comment: This only hides the problem! You want to show the "+10!" only for 5ms, so for one frame. Try to show it for 1000ms and you'll see that it will not work as expected. It'll still be visible for only one frame.

Comment: Please don't write `ANSWERED` in your question. You should click on the check mark on the left of the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

1. Your system is slow enough that immediately after setting that boolean in the first `if` in the `update()` method, you land in the second `if` and you set the variable to `false` (I find this pretty unlikely but if you're running in some sort of emulator maybe?). Might be worth putting some logging in place to confirm that the drawing happens in between your setting of this variable to true and false.
2. The `plusScore` variable in your `update()` method is not the same one as the `plusScore` variable in your `draw()` method. Are both these methods in the same class? I can tell that your `plusScore` variable is a field from your code snippets but if those two code snippets are not in the same class you are dealing with two completely separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your `plusScore` will be set to false every time `update` gets called. Try this:

```
public class CheckTime {
     public static void main(String []args){
        int tempTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        long longTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("As long: " + longTime);
        System.out.println("As int: " + tempTime);
        System.out.println("Check: " + (tempTime + 5 < longTime));
     }
}
```

The output is:

```
As long: 1490102795366
As int: -250856346
Check: true
```

This means: because you are casting the current time from `long` to `int` you get an overflow. And that's why your last if-statement in `update` will always be true.

You should try to avoid comparing two different types like `int` and `long` (except you are 110% sure it's the same but then you should be able to use the same types). Change `tempTime` to long, remove the cast and it will work.

Another hint: `plusScore` and `tempTime + 5 <= System.currentTimeMillis()` has the same semantics in this example. So you can get rid of `plusScore` and use the if-statement from `update` in `draw` to get the same behaviour.